# How to render a partial in a plugin from a plugin helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, render, partial

I have a helper in my plugin **test_plugin/lib/test_helper.rb**:

```
module TestHelper
  def test_render
    render 'test_plugin/test_partial'
  end
end
```

I have a partial **test_plugin/app/views/test_plugin/_test_partial.html.erb**:

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

In my application **app/views/tests/index.html.erb** when I do this:

```
<%= test_render %>
```

I get the following error:

> Missing partial
>   test_plugin/test_partial with
>   {:locale=>[:en, :en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rjs,
>   :rhtml, :haml, :builder, :rxml, :erb]}
>   in view paths
>   "/home/####/workspace/my_application/app/views"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me on Rails 2.3.5 (ie: it searches for this partial in `vendor/plugins/test_plugin/app/views/test_plugin`):

vendor/plugins/test_plugin/init.rb

```
require 'test_plugin'
```

vendor/plugins/test_plugin/lib/test_plugin.rb

```
require 'test_plugin_helpers'

# Helpers will be available in all controllers
ActionController::Base.send :include, TestPlugin::Helpers

# Helpers will be available in the views
ActionView::Base.send :include, TestPlugin::Helpers
```

vendor/plugins/test_plugin/lib/test_plugin_helpers.rb

```
module TestPlugin
  module Helpers
    def test_render
      render 'test_plugin/test_partial'
    end
  end
end
```

vendor/plugins/test_plugin/app/views/test_plugin/_test_partial.html.erb

```
Yuppie!
```

app/views/test.html.erb

```
<%= test_render %>
```

Something similar should work also in Rails3.